# MYSQL: query to combine count

Tags: mysql, sql

the sql:

```
SELECT 
id, COUNT(id) AS Counter
FROM tableA  
GROUP BY id
```

the result:

[image]

the goal is to do like below:

[image]

to combine the (NULL ID) with ID=09 so that it will 0+1=1, give proper naming to the id will be great too, like

```
ID             Counter
NULLWITH09        1
THE 01           467
THE 02            8
```

any help would be great.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

untested, but something like this:

```
SELECT 
'THE ' +id, COUNT(id) AS Counter
FROM tableA
where id is not null and id<>9  
GROUP BY id
UNION ALL
SELECT 
'null and 9', COUNT(*) AS Counter
FROM tableA
where id is null or id=9
```